# hibernate doesn't get the next_val of the sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I use the postgresql database.

I have a serial field in one table, the serial field is not primary key, and it is  used to allocate port number to avoid duplication, the serial starts from 30001 for example.

I use hibernate to insert table, but the field is always 0.

My sequence description:

```
last_value    | bigint  | 30001

start_value   | bigint  | 30001

increment_by  | bigint  | 1

max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807

min_value     | bigint  | 30001
```

and my entity java code is:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "XXX")
@SequenceGenerator(name="XXX_seq",sequenceName="XXX_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue = 30001)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="XXX_seq")
```

Because the field is not primary key, so I don't use the `@Id`.

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As `@GeneratedValue` can only be used with `@Id` (answered earlier by tom)

> Provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values
>   of primary keys. The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a
>   primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass in
>   conjunction with the Id annotation.

[DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

**Solution**

You can get max value by query like: *it returns you the max used port*

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select max(u.portId) from XXXX u");
List<Long> list = query.getResultList();
return (list.isEmpty() || list.get(0) == null ? maxId : list.get(0));
```

Comment: the `select max` method must resolve the concurrency problem.

Comment: To achieve that you can use database locks.

Comment: True, solution are always more than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GeneratedValue
```

only works on identifiers (@Id)

You could use:

- an Insert Trigger
- a separate Table where you store the last used number
- Database specific solution (Postgres can have a Sequence on a Column if i'm not mistaken)

Not really JPA but I don't think that can be done automagically by JPA/Hibernate